# Why does SELECT 'a'='b'='c' return 1 in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

I was doing some homework for my security class involving SQL injections. I found that I could do a shorter SQL injection than the typical `' OR '1'=1` example. Instead I could do `'='`. Typing this is in to the password field of a typical login boxes gives a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username='user' AND password=''='';
```

It turns out that `password=''=''` evaluates to `1`, allowing the SQL injection to work.

After doing some more testing, I saw that if I test if a string is equal to 0, it returns 1:

```
SELECT 0='a';
```

So in my example, `password=''` would evaluate to 0 and `0=''` would end up evaluating to 1.

My testing showed me *how* this is happening, but I want know *why* this happens (i.e why is `0='a'` true?.

Comment: Search for `banana` on this page: http://grimoire.ca/mysql/choose-something-else

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As documented under [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/type-conversion.html), comparisons between a string and an integer will be performed numerically:

> - In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (real) numbers.

Therefore, the operands are converted to floating-point numbers and then compared.

Conversion of a string to a float will consider every numeric character (and the first period or exponentiation character) encountered up to the first non-numeric character.  Therefore `'hello'` or `'a'` will be truncated to `''` (and thereby cast to zero) whereas `'123.45e6foo789'` would truncate to `'123.45e6'` (and thereby cast to 123,450,000).

Thus one can see how `0='a'` is true: it is compared as `0=0`.

That `password=''=''` is true (*provided that* `password` is a non-empty string, or a non-zero numeric) comes about because the first comparison results in zero (false), which forces the second comparison to be performed numerically (thus converting `''` to zero for comparison with the zero result of the first comparison).

Answer (score 4):

Mysql sees the comparison and converts the string to an integer,but this results in an invalid integer so it cast it to 0. 0=0 so its true(1)

Answer (score 0):

For SELECT 0='a', 0='';

```
1. type of 0 is int 
2. type of 'a' is char  then CAST( 'a' AS UNSIGNED ) or CAST( '' AS UNSIGNED ) will be 0
```

Convert char to int then 0=0 evaluates as true in your case 1.
In:

```
select 'A'='a', 0=0, '0'='a',0='a1';
```

all columns will  be true, but for:

```
select 0='1a';
```

will be false because CAST( '1a' AS UNSIGNED ) is 1.

```
mysql> SELECT 'asadsadsa' = 'a', 0 = 'az', cast( 'az' AS unsigned ) , 'asadsadsa' = 'a' = 'az', 0 =0;
      +-------------------+----------+--------------------------+--------------------------+------+
      | 'asadsadsa' = 'a' | 0 = 'az' | cast( 'az' AS unsigned ) | 'asadsadsa' = 'a' = 'az' | 0 =0 |
      +-------------------+----------+--------------------------+--------------------------+------+
      |                 0 |        1 |                        0 |                        1 |    1 |
      +-------------------+----------+--------------------------+--------------------------+------+
      1 row in set, 3 warnings (0.00 sec)

      Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'az'
      Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'az'
      Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'az'
```

Comment: Why is casting 'a' as an unsigned give you 0? I'm not very familiar with SQL, but shouldn't it give the ASCII value for 'a'?

Comment: Read more here
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Comment: Like in Php (int)"a1" =0, and '1a'=1, I used this exemple to show how MySQL converts the string; see comparison between 2 diferent types.